# How to specify server certificate for a self-contained Kestrel/Blazor application deployed on a production server?

Tags: asp.net, https, .net-core, ssl-certificate, kestrel-http-server

I created a Blazor application to be run using Kestrel (.Net core 3.1).

1. Import NuGet package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate
2. Add the following code in ConfigureService() in Startup.cs.

```
    services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();
    services.AddSingleton<ValidateAuthentication>();
```

3. Add the following code in Configure() in Startup.cs. They are added between app.UseRouting(); and app.UseEndpoints(...;

```
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseMiddleware<ValidateAuthentication>();
```

4. Add the class

```
internal class ValidateAuthentication : IMiddleware
{
  public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
  {
    if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        await next(context);
    else
        await context.ChallengeAsync();
  }
}
```

5. Add the following code in the `Program.cs` (To make sure the remote machine can access the website)

```
     webBuilder.UseUrls(new string[] { "https://0.0.0.0:5001", "http://0.0.0.0:5000" });
```

I published (as self hosted) the application to a local folder and it works fine on my PC. Running `.\myApp.exe` and then browsing http://localhost.5000 will redirect to https://localhost:5001 and show the page.

Then the published folder was copied to a Windows 2012 Server. However, running the application gets error:

```
PS C:\Website\Portal> .\MyApp.exe
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Unable to start Kestrel.
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the defau
lt developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.
To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run
'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'.
For more information on configuring HTTPS see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848054.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions, Action`1 configure
Options)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.AddressesStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext con
text)
```

How to specify a server certificate for the application?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution or resource for this issue?

Comment: VS should prompt you to add development certificate when you start debugging. Also you can run this command to trust dev certificates 

dotnet dev-certs https --trust

Answer (score 4):

[This Microsoft Docs article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/docker-https?view=aspnetcore-3.1) explains how to startup an ASP.Net Core app with certificates when it ships as a Docker container. You basically set ennvironment variables, e.g.

- ASPNETCORE_URLS
- ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT
- ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path
- ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password

I guess you may do the same on the host directly but keep in mind that those settings won't be isolated and may affect other apps. Also note that you would be storing a password in an environment variable. I also found [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-2-1-https-improvements/) explaining how to configure Kestrel via the launch settings json.

I came across this question by accident. Solution is not tested. Just replying since there is no better suggestion yet.

Comment: And when not in Docker container? I have plain Windows Server 2019.